# Calling function inside a function which requires a parameterin PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I have a module with various functions. I recently added a function. This function accepts a parameter, processes some data and calls another function which is inside it. This function accepts a string array as a parameter. Below is the code:

```
        Function Get-CMClientInstall{
        some code..........

        Analyze-ClientInstall $clientcheck


        Function Analyze-ClientInstall
        {
            #[CmdletBinding()]

            PARAM (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$CCMClients)
        }
     }
```

Below is the error message:

```
The term 'Analyze-ClientInstall' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
 Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ConfigMgrCommands\ConfigMgrCommands.psm1:475 char:34
+             Analyze-ClientInstall <<<<  $clientcheck
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Analyze-ClientInstall:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can someone please advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell reads the file and execute the content synchronously. When you call the function PowerShell doesn't have a clue that it exist cause it didn't interpret it yet. Move to call to the function AFTER the function declaration.

```
    Function Get-CMClientInstall{
    some code..........


    Function Analyze-ClientInstall
    {
        #[CmdletBinding()]

        PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$CCMClients)
    }


    Analyze-ClientInstall $clientcheck
 }
```